# Android: how should an app handle the device's language change

Tags: android, locale

Actually I'm handling 3 languages in my app so I have:

`values/strings.xml`

`values-it/strings.xml`

`values-de/strings.xml`

When I install the app, it is properly installed in the current language of the device.
But if I change the language of the device, the language of the app doesn't switch. I have to reinstall it to switch the language.

I've seent that this happens also to other apps, but not to all. The "big" ones (whatsapp, viber, all google's, etc) change.

So the question is: how can an app follow the device's language change ?

Comment: All apps change the language automatically unless you have disabled it in manifest (eg. with `android:configChanges="locale"`). See [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should work without any problem unless you have             `android:configChanges="locale"`  specified for your activity in your Androidmanifest file

Comment: Well, I don't have it specified but the language doesn't change.

Comment: Ok, you're right, my fault. If I force the app to stop and restart it, the language is correct so I should check the onResume phase I guess. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

I add an answer to help someone with the same problem.
First thing to do to get an event that the language was changed, is to add this to the manifest:

```
<activity
    ....
    android:configChanges="layoutDirection|locale"
    ....
</activity>
```

Please note the `layoutDirection`: **without it, it doesn't work!** Only `locale` does not trigger the event. It has something to do with *right-to-left languages* but I didn't investigate further.

Then, in the activity, add a:

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig)
{
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}
```

This is called when the app is resumed and the `newConfig` contains all the informations needed, for example *newConfig.locale.getLanguage()*

How to then update the language in your app, is up to you but reading the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html) suggested by @StenSoft would be a good decision.